# How to find missing and modified rows with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am experimenting with some hypothetical dataframes to find missing values in `df2` as following using `merge` function:

```
dict_a = {'File': ["Orange", "Apple", "Kiwi", "Cherry", "Grapes"], 'Modified':[1, 15, 30, 24, 16]}
dict_b = {'File': ["Apple", "Orange", "Grapes"], 'Modified':[0, 1, 16]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_b)

display(df1)
display(df2)
```

[image]

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',indicator='Exist')
display(df3)
```

With this result, it tells me that there are rows with 'left_only' characteristic i.e. they could be modified or, missing.

[image]

What's the efficient way to mark the missing ones as "missing"?

Comment: If you could explain what you actually want as expected output that'd help... it might just be `how='outer'` in the join will be enough but...

Comment: The output I expect is that in `df3`, the row with `Apple` index should say 'modified' in 'Exist' column and rest will be untouched or say, 'missing'. That way I will know exactly what missing values and what are modified values in `df2` compared to `df1`.

Comment: Okay... but you don't have an actual index... (`merge` is specifically for columns...) - are you going to come across cases where by there's multiple repeats of the "File" column in either DF?

Comment: No, there won't be any repeated values in the `File` column but `Modified` could have..

Comment: Maybe I should do right join with `df1` and `df2` as well and find `Apple` in `right_only` and then mark `Apple` in `df3` as 'modified`?

Comment: Umnm.. can think of a few ways but not quite sure what'd be considered "efficient way" as you need to look at both sides regardless

Comment: By 'efficient way', I meant just a way with minimum overhead or minimum steps as possible as the dataframe could have a large size. I thought 'merge' was best possible way because it can match rows which are in different order in dataframes i.e. regardless of their index.

Comment: Did you also want to retain the value of 15 for apple? Or know it had conflicting values? Eg... did you want some values retained or just happy to know there's agreement/disagreement/missing?

Comment: I wouldn't need to care about the value. But later on if needed I think I could easily recheck the value by looking for `Apple` since all the row values for `File` would be unique.

Comment: okay... I've got an idea - gimme two ticks... I'm not 100% sure on it, but i'll post it as an answer as it won't quite fit in a comment, but if it doesn't work, be kind, and I'll just delete it :)

Answer (score 1):

Taking your original code:

```
dict_a = {'File': ["Orange", "Apple", "Kiwi", "Cherry", "Grapes"], 'Modified':[1, 15, 30, 24, 16]}
dict_b = {'File': ["Apple", "Orange", "Grapes"], 'Modified':[0, 1, 16]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_b)
```

Join using an *outer* join, then group by "File", then do a bit of grouping, aggs and optional replacement, eg:

```
m = (
    df1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator='Exist', sort=False)
    .groupby('File', sort=False, as_index=False)
    .agg({'Modified': 'first', 'Exist': 'last'})
    # optionally
    .replace({'Exist': {'both': 'matched', 'right_only': 'modified', 'left_only': 'missing'}})
)
```

That'll give you:

```
     File  Modified     Exist
0  Orange         1   matched
1   Apple        15  modified
2    Kiwi        30   missing
3  Cherry        24   missing
4  Grapes        16   matched
```

Comment: Your mileage may vary a bit on this... as it may be that the sorts aren't quite doing what I expect here...

Comment: The result seems as expected, but I'll test the code to see what's happening and respond back.

Comment: @cpx it relies on the fact that a `right_only` will appear after a `left_only` - and I don't know if the implementation of `merge` guarantees that... I'm going to check it out later though (when I can find the time)... if you find out before then... it'd be appreciated if you could let me know - thanks!

Comment: I see. But I don't care about the order of the rows, so you can just sort it any way to make `right_only` appear after a `left_only`. The implementation could change in future, so I won't want to rely on those assumptions.

Comment: @cpx what I mean is that if there's a guarantee that right_only will appear after a left_only on an outer join.... so it wouldn't matter the order you put them into the merge for instance... you say you were trying to use merge - so this might be a possible solution... however, like mentioned, it does depend on ordering that may/may not be guaranteed, you can always force the ordering to do some things or just run multiple set scans etc...

Comment: I posted a solution as well, would you say it will work as I expect it to work without much complications or "may/may not be guarantees"?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straight-forward solution how I was thinking about doing which I expect to work as guarantee.

```
left_only = df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator='Exist')

# Right join will only contain 'modified' files as 'right_only'
right_only = df1.merge(df2, how='right', indicator='Exist')

# Get rows where value is 'right_only'
modified_rows = right_only.loc[right_only.Exist == 'right_only']

# Set type as 'categorical'
df3['Exist'] = df3.Exist.astype(str)

df3.loc[df3["File"].isin(list(modified_rows['File'])), "Exist"] = "modified"
display(df3)
```

Comment: first note - something I came to learn early on - always prefer to use df['Column'] - to access a column, even if you're pretty darn sure it's never going to conflict with an attribute access... I'll have a look at this code when I can